# how to make ngclick work like toggle?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have taken a span and after clicking the span, it adds 1 to it. but what i need is, ngclick should add only once to whatever value is inside the span. Again for another click it should subtract 1 from it. It should not iterate continuously.
i am getting {{tvshow.episode.ratings.loved}} from json data.
 pls help.

```
//html
<html>
<body>
    <span class="label likeme"  ng-click="tvshow.episode.ratings.loved = tvshow.episode.ratings.loved + 1" ng-init="{{tvshow.episode.ratings.loved}}">
        <i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i> {{tvshow.episode.ratings.loved}}</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

//view.html

```
<span ng-click="doOneTimeOnly();">{{tvshow.episode.ratings.loved}}</div>
```

//controller.js

```
  $scope.times = 0;

    $scope.doOneTimeOnly = function () {
      if ( $scope.times < 1) {
        //do my stuff with the tvshow.episode.ratings.loved
        //.................
       $scope.times += 1;
      }
    }
```

Actually i dont think this makes sense but is what you are asking for :P

this can also be easily moved to a custom directive like `directive('ngOneClickOnly');` for example

Comment: {{tvshow.episode.ratings.loved}} can be any number from 0 to 100.

Comment: @madhukumar yes this is how you run your ng-click only 1 time, updated

Comment: it is iterating continuously.

Answer (score 0):

now here you have one option ng-disabled with this you can click only once.

```
<script>
    angular.module("my_app",[])

    .controller("my_ctr",function($scope){
        $scope.skm=true;
        $scope.mmmmmm=function()
        {

            if($scope.skm==false)
            {
                alert("first time you clicked");                
            }
            else
            {       
                alert("now you cant click");
                $scope.skm=false;
            }
        }
    })
    </script>

<body ng-app="my_app" ng-controller="my_ctr">
<button ng-click="mmmmmm()" ng-disabled="!skm">hii</button> 
</body>
```

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>   include this

Comment: this code is working for me....tell me whats going wrong with your code while your using this code..